# Silverlight Support for 3D

Tags: silverlight

I heard about ZAM 3D that it is the support of 3D in Silverlight , and I want to know is that true or not , or if silverlight support it by it's own , or what is the best choice for me to make 3d using silverlight

please answer as soon as you can

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight 4 supports "perspective 3D" which allow you to project controls in a 3D manner. You can therefore perform movements like rotations, perspective effects and animations. this technology benefits from hardware acceleration, but is rather limited.

Some libraries add true 3D support in Silverlight, such as [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/), but they can't provide hardware acceleration and are feature incomplete.

True 3D support is on the roadmap for Silverlight 5 however.